# Where can I find the emit() function implementation used in MongoDB's map/reduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, emit

I am trying to develop a deeper understanding of map/reduce in MongoDB.

I figure the best way to accomplish this is to look at emit's actual implementation. Where can I find it?

Even better would just be a simple implementation of `emit()`. In the MongoDB documentation, they show a way to troubleshoot `emit()` by writing your own, but the basic implementation they give is really too basic.

I'd like to understand how the grouping is taking place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the definition you are looking for is located here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/commands/mr.cpp#L886

There is quite a lot of context needed though to fully understand what is going on. I confess, I do not.

Comment: yeah quite a bit of context needed :) any idea where to find the js version?

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/third_party/js-1.7/jsconfig.h#L44

I think that is the version the database js runtime uses

Answer (score 0):

1.Mongo's required JS version is no longer in O.Powell's url, which is dead. I cannot find it.

2.The below code seems to be the snippet of most interest. This cpp function, switchMode, computes the emit function to use. It is currently at;
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/commands/mr.cpp#L815

3.I was trying to see if emit has a default to include the _id key, which seems to occur via _mrMap, not shown here. Elsewhere it is initialized to {}, the empty map.

```
void State::switchMode(bool jsMode) {
    _jsMode = jsMode;
    if (jsMode) {
        // emit function that stays in JS
        _scope->setFunction("emit",
                            "function(key, value) {"
                            " if (typeof(key) === 'object') {"
                            " _bailFromJS(key, value);"
                            " return;"
                            " }"
                            " ++_emitCt;"
                            " var map = _mrMap;"
                            " var list = map[key];"
                            " if (!list) {"
                            " ++_keyCt;"
                            " list = [];"
                            " map[key] = list;"
                            " }"
                            " else"
                            " ++_dupCt;"
                            " list.push(value);"
                            "}");
        _scope->injectNative("_bailFromJS", _bailFromJS, this);
    }
    else {
        // emit now populates C++ map
        _scope->injectNative( "emit" , fast_emit, this );
    }
}
```